# An error occurred when calling PyTorch from C++

Tags: python, c++, torch

I try to use PyTorch from C++ but it cannot work well.
Command `import torch` works well in Command prompt. I am not sure the reason but it works even though c++ when I install torch without CUDA.

This is a code.

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import torch");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that it works for example `PyRun_SimpleString("import numpy as np");`.
This is an error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\GreenTea\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1.
```

I'm using 
Torch==1.2.0+cu92 
torchvision==0.4.0+cu92 
Cuda==9.2 
Anaconda==5.1.0 
Windows==10 
Visual Studio==2019 
I also tried the other combinations.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use `pytorch` with `C++` there is an API for that, see [PyTorch C++ API docs](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/).

Currently it is in beta phase and may undergo breaking changes so look out for that, but the usage is pretty similar to Python API and well thought-out hence if you know some `C++` it shouldn't be much of a trouble (see [End to End example](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/frontend.html#end-to-end-example)).

If you want to use trained network or feel better within Python environment, you can train network with it and just use `C++` API for inference just by loading the network compiled with `torchscript`. See [this official tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_export.html) for easy to follow example how to do that.

I don't think what you are trying to do is supported and might be hard to get help if you follow this approach further.